# Convert sumproduct formula into a generic formula that can be used across all sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Data-2017'!W1:EZ1="Enemy 1")*('Data-2017'!W3:EZ1361="Yes")*('Data-2017'!J3:J1361=$T$4))
```

where `Data-2017` is the sheet name.

I want to convert it into a generic formula that references a sheet name in a cell.

I have tried converting to following but failed:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT("'" & $D$3 & "'!" & "W1:EZ1=" & CHAR(34) & "Enemy 1" & CHAR(34))*("'" & $D$3 & "'!" & "W3:EZ1361=" & CHAR(34) & "Enemy 1" & CHAR(34))*("'" & $D$3 & "'!" & "J3:J1361=" & T4))
```

where `D3` is the cell for sheet name, `T4` is another value in to suffice the condition.

Answer (score 0):

INDIRECT only goes around the cell references not the whole formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'" & $D$3 & "'!" & "W1:EZ1")="Enemy 1")*(INDIRECT("'" & $D$3 & "'!" & "W3:EZ1361")="Yes")*(INDIRECT("'" & $D$3 & "'!" & "J3:J1361")=$T$4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out by accident after further research:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'"&$D$3&"'!$W$1:$EZ$1")="Enemy 1")*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$3&"'!$W$3:$EZ$1500")="Yes")*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$3&"'!$J$3:$J$1500")=T$4))
```